# How can I hide then show multiple Divs when checkbox is checked using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several checkbox inputs on one page with yes/no answers. I would like to hide the information in the toggle div until the no checkbox is clicked. I would like a simplified JQuery code that will work for each instance and the divs will show independently upon a checked "no" asnwer. Thanks in advance for any help or feedback!

```
<div>
<ul class="rank">
<li>
    <label>Do you like the colour blue?</label>
    <fieldset>
        <label><input  class="no" type="checkbox" /> No</label>
        <label><input  class="yes" type="checkbox" /> Yes</label>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="toggle">
        No, I do not like the colour blue!
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Do you like the colour red?</label>
    <fieldset>
        <label><input  class="no" type="checkbox" /> No</label>
        <label><input  class="yes" type="checkbox" /> Yes</label>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="toggle">
        No, I do not like the colour red!
    </div>
</li>
<ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".toggle").hide();
    $(".no").click(function() {
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(".toggle").show(500);
} else {
    $(".toggle").hide(500);
}
});

</script>
```

Comment: In order for anything we say to count as feedback you would have to actually try to accomplish the task at hand, run into an error/problem, post it here and receive help.

Comment: I have tried to use the following script yet it hides all divs at once. I am looking for each div to work independently. This is the script I have tried using.<script type="text/javascript">
$(".toggle").hide();
    $(".no").click(function() {
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(".toggle").show(500);
} else {
    $(".toggle").hide(500);
}
});

</script>

Comment: Smells like homework...

Comment: Actually just new to JQuery but thanks for the sarcasm. We can't all be experts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work :

```
$(".toggle").hide();
$(".no").change(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.toggle').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

If you want the animation :

```
$(".toggle").hide();
$(".no").change(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.toggle')[this.checked ? 'show' : 'hide'](500);
});
```

---

## Edit

UXwise, you should use radio button instead of checkbox for what you are trying to achieve. Once you change to radio button, this code above will not work, you need some modification.

This should work :

```
$(".toggle").hide();
$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
    var toShow = this.checked && this.value == 'no';
    $(this).closest('li').find('.toggle')[toShow ? 'show' : 'hide'](500);
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nrcC4/1/

Of course, instead of `class="no"`, i've used `value="no"`. It is much more ergonomique.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at the answer of IT ppl, but the script is to global.
If you check no, both toggle will respons.

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate a specific related toggle.

PS: I would advice to use a radio button with a yes/no answer or a dropdown.

http://jsfiddle.net/d1m5n/Nj3gr/

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<ul class="rank">
<li>
    <label>Do you like the colour blue?</label>
    <fieldset>
        <label><input  class="no" type="checkbox" /> No</label>
        <label><input  class="yes" type="checkbox" /> Yes</label>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="toggle">
        No, I do not like the colour blue!
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Do you like the colour red?</label>
    <fieldset>
        <label><input  class="no" type="checkbox" /> No</label>
        <label><input  class="yes" type="checkbox" /> Yes</label>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="toggle">
        No, I do not like the colour red!
    </div>
</li>
<ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".toggle").hide();
    $(".no").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parents("li").find('.toggle').show(500);
    } else {
        $(this).parents("li").find('.toggle').hide(500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.no').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().parent().next('.toggle').toggle(); 
});

.toggle {
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fuLUF/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".toggle").hide();
$(".no").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("li").find(".toggle").toggle();
});
```

[JS fiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/7xy4g/1/)

Comment: Thanks so much! This works and does exactly what I was looking for! I've spent days trying to get a script that would work. Many thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative with delegated-event approach, which (maybe) gives you a bit more dynamism and performances.

```
$(".toggle").hide();

$(".rank li").on('click', '.no', function(e) {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(e.delegateTarget).find(".toggle").show(500);
    } else {
        $(e.delegateTarget).find(".toggle").hide(500);
    }
});
```